# What Event for ComboBox to change text color while typing

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox, textchanged

I'm programming in WinForms.
I have a ComboBox set with an initial gray ForeColor. My goal is to change the text color of this ComboBox when the user start to type something.

I tried to use `_TextChanged` and `TextUpdate` Events but don't work.

```
private void ComboBox1_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
}
```

I already used the Event `_SelectedIndexChanged` to change the text color when the user select an item from the drop-down list, and it works well, but the text remains gray if the user types something (there is an `AutoCompleteCustomSource` collection associated to the ComboBox so the user can write instead to use the drop-down list).

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**
I have solved this way:

Registering in `Form1.Designer.cs`:

```
this.ComboBox1.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.ComboBox1_KeyUp);`
```

Using this code:

```
private void ComboBox1_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    ComboBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [KeyUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821477.aspx), [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197678.aspx), or [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196758.aspx) events fired by the textbox. You probably don't want `KeyPress` for this purpose.  `TextChanged` fires when the text has already been changed, which is why the new character being typed doesn't have a different color when you subscribe to it.

Comment: Thanks so much @user1895086!
Although it is not yet clear to me the difference between `KeyUp`, `KeyDown` and `KeyPress`, I have solved this way:<br><br>

1) registering in `Form1.Designer.cs`<br>
    this.ComboBox1.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.ComboBox1_KeyUp);<br><br>

2) using this code<br>
    private void ComboBox1_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
        }

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `KeyUp` event?  [MSDN Keyup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821477.aspx)

You should be able to subscribe to this event and do whatever you want inside it.

Comment: Thanks so much @tjcertified!
Although it is not yet clear to me the difference between `KeyUp`, `KeyDown` and `KeyPress`, I have solved this way:<br><br>

1) registering in `Form1.Designer.cs`<br>
    this.ComboBox1.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.ComboBox1_KeyUp);<br><br>

2) using this code<br>
    private void ComboBox1_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
        }

Comment: All of those events are related. <code>KeyDown</code> happens when you push down on a key, <code>KeyUp</code> happens after you release a key, and <code>KeyPress</code> happens after both of the previous events.

Comment: So a very tiny difference. Thanks again for your explanation and for your time. ;)